# How can I pass table valued parameter to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

How to pass a table valued parameter to a stored procedure in Entity Framework using ExecuteSqlCommand or SqlQuery method?

Following is my code -

```
DataTable dataTable=new DataTable();

dataTable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(bool));

dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec stored_proc @tvp",
    new SqlParameter() { 
                         SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, 
                         ParameterName = "@tvp", Value = dataTable 
                        });
```

This throws an exception saying 'The table type parameter '@tvp' must have a valid type name.'

Comment: This question is about C# Entity Framework, right?

Comment: yes. It is Entity Framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.ArgumentException: The table type parameter must have a valid type name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817997/system-argumentexception-the-table-type-parameter-must-have-a-valid-type-name)